# unable to build kernel driver - Debian Jessie stackprotector

Tags: linux, debian, driver

We have one Debian Jessie installation into which I am attempting to install a kernel driver.

Basically, upon build the makefile drops out with :

> Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler.

We're on kernel 3.16 with gcc 4.9.1

I'm fairly sure that 4.9.1 supports -fstack-protector so I'm stumped.

Would very much appreciate some help getting this built.